# How to replace the threshold in a center-hinged exterior porch door?

Tags: doors, threshold

I have a center-hinged porch door leading out onto my deck. Viewed from the inside, the right panel of the porch door swings inward, and the left panel is fixed. The wood below the aluminum threshold has mostly rotted away, and I would like to remove the threshold and reflash and replace it. I've seen several videos of people replacing thresholds on single or double doors where the door panels are hinged to the side jambs, but not on a door like this where the panels are hinged to the center mullpost, which goes through the threshold. Is it possible to cleanly replace the threshold on a door like this, without replacing the entire door unit?

[image: Center-Hinged Porch Door]

Answer (score 1):

Especially this time of year, it is probably more wise to to repair the rotted wood in place.

- Scrape away the rotted door sill material,
- apply wood hardener to what's left (be careful not to get that stuff on any exposed surfaces, and keep it off of your hands somehow),
- use an epoxy based wood filler to create a new sill edge,
- apply your flashing,
- sneak a bead of sealant between the new flashing and the threshold, and
- caulk the joint between the new sill edge and the ground.

If you install metal flashing, be sure that there's some path for water to diffuse out of the sill so that it can evaporate.

Comment: I have to admit that wood hardener and epoxy, while inelegant, do an adequate job and require less futzing about than trying to actually replace the wood. One thing to be aware of: different epoxy putties cure at different speeds, and a hot day can cause some to cure before you can really get them in place. I've had the best luck with the ones that come as a tube of doughy putty, two parts concentric with each other, that you kneed to mix;.the one I used cured slowly, but started out thick enough to apply and shape. Do paint afterwards to protect what's left of the wood.